# How to decode QRCODE using C++ opencv library on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, qr-code

I am working with opencv c++ library to decode Qrcode.Here I given sample test code which is from this website: https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-qr-code-scanner-c-and-python/

When I am compiling this test program I am getting following error:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:29:3: error: ‘QRCodeDetector’ was not declared in this scope
   QRCodeDetector qrDecoder = QRCodeDetector::QRCodeDetector();
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cc:33:22: error: ‘qrDecoder’ was not declared in this scope
   std::string data = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(inputImage, bbox, rectifiedImage)
```

How to resolve this error?

```
test.cc:
//https://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-qr-code-scanner-c-and-python/
#include <opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void display(Mat &im, Mat &bbox)
{
  int n = bbox.rows;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
  {
    line(im, Point2i(bbox.at<float>(i,0),bbox.at<float>(i,1)), Point2i(bbox.at<float>((i+1) % n,0), bbox.at<float>((i+1) % n,1)), Scalar(255,0,0), 3);
  }
  imshow("Result", im);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Read image
  Mat inputImage;

  inputImage = imread(argv[1]);

  QRCodeDetector qrDecoder = QRCodeDetector::QRCodeDetector();

  Mat bbox, rectifiedImage;

  std::string data = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(inputImage, bbox, rectifiedImage);
  if(data.length()>0)
  {
    cout << "Decoded Data : " << data << endl;

    display(inputImage, bbox);
    rectifiedImage.convertTo(rectifiedImage, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("Rectified QRCode", rectifiedImage);

    waitKey(0);
  }
  else
    cout << "QR Code not detected" << endl;
}

//compile
g++ test.cc -o test `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to include a header file for `QRCodeDetector`. Are you using OpenCV 4.0?

Comment: As this website shows QRCoderDetector is part of <opencv2/objdetect.hpp> header file which I included. https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/de/dc3/classcv_1_1QRCodeDetector.html

Comment: Well yes but in _your_ installation if you look at that header file does it in fact define `QRCodeDetector`? Have you checked?

Comment: I am using OPENCV-2 .So what I have to include I cant getting it?Have you tried to compile this code?@barny

Comment: No I haven’t. The example you link to refers to OpenCV version 4.0. The error is saying `QRCodeDetector` isn’t defined. All I’m asking you to do is to check that the header files which presumably should be defining it (if they are the same version as the example you link to) actually *do* define it. Is that so difficult? If they don’t define `QRCodeDetector` then you *will* get a compilation error. Do the header files define `QRCodeDetector`?

Comment: the header file(opencv2/objdetect.hpp) which I included is not having that class defined @barny

Comment: OK so you are not using the same version of opencv as the example: that’s why it won’t compile. Resolving that is up to you.

Comment: ok thanks I will look out it @barny

Answer (score 0):

First of all, code is compatible with OpenCV 4.0, so be sure that you are using OpenCV 4.0. If you are using OpenCV 4.0, you may have refered different version of OpenCV path in eclipse.

For solution, there is two steps.

**Step1**

From Terminal, type *pkg-config --cflags opencv4*. Output will be like *I/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv*. Copy output and paste it place which is shown in first link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WSBEOaSF6JJvOiUSI_kop8wnRaK8TOIt

**Steps2**

Again from terminal, type *pkg-config --libs opencv4*. Output will be like *L/usr/local/lib*. Copy output and paste it place which is shown in second link. Than add headers referances to Libraries(-l) section like shown in link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VYJHNV10P8oj_pwaUh3GZJwWu8vDmUxA

This steps will be solution your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Referring thread below (same problem but has all details): https://forum.opencv.org/t/quirc-error-in-opencv-4/6804/3
On a Ubuntu 22.04.1

On Linux OpenCV4.* build *detects* the presence of 3rd party libs. To make it use bundled QUIRC use (for cmake): `-DBUILD_QUIRC=ON -DQUIRC=ON`

Full command would be like:

```
cmake       -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/OpenCV47 \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D WITH_TBB=ON \
            -D WITH_V4L=ON \
            -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
            -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
            -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -DBUILD_QUIRC=ON -DQUIRC=ON \
             ..
```

Above command worked for me; other options can be adjusted to suit your needs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).